# One Page Scroll plugin not working for swipe scroll on the ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll

I have used the One Page Scroll Plugin on my website.Below is the plugin page
https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

The scroll works fine on desktops, but I am facing a problem on the ipad.
The swipe scroll on the ipad is scrolling 4 pages down when I scroll once on my website.

Please how do I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have javascript DOM event object like : 
ontouchcancel, ontouchend, ontouchmove and ontouchstart
which can make scroll effect.

Have in mind that jquery and etc are built on top of the javascript so the basically use similar functions. 
Without the code or working platform provided by you... i can't really tell you anything but redirect you to w3schools.

[w3schools javascript DOM Event Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: The page structure is as below. And jquery.onepage-scroll.js is used.

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="main">
    <section class="page1">...</section>
    <section class="page2">...</section>
    <section class="page3">...</section>
    <section class="page4">...</section>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

How to use jquery.swipe-events.js on my page to enable swipe scroll for ipad.